# ServiceStack: Change base path of all routes in self-hosted application

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-bsd

I have a self-hosted application with many routes set up. Rather than going through each one and changing the route to be `/api/<route>` where `<route>` is the existing route, I was wondering if I can prefix each route with `/api` when I start the application? I know its possible in an IIS hosted enviroment by setting it in the `web.config` but I am not sure if its possible in a self-hosted environment?

Answer (score 5):

@EliGassert's answer is right for ServiceStack v4 self-hosted applications. This is the requirements to change the base path of all routes in a ServiceStack v3 self-hosted application.

## ServiceStack v3:

In you AppHost `Configure` method, you need to set `ServiceStackHanderFactoryPath` to the desired prefix.

```cs
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig {
        ServiceStackHandlerFactoryPath = "api"
    });
}
```

When you set your listener you must also append the prefix:

```cs
appHost.Start("http://*:9000/api/");
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah I was talking with @Eli Gassert on Jabbr about this. I tried it and then my index.html page failed to load, returned 404 when I navigated to /index.html or /api/index.html hence why he made a note.

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff Ah ok, one sec, I reckon I can solve that too. I have an incline as to what that is. Let me just run a test.

Comment: Ideally I'd liek to serve the static HTML at root and then all my services on /api

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff I am not having an issue serving up the static html from the `/api` directory after adding the `ServiceStackHandlerFactoryPath = "api"`. So I see `/api/index.html`. But it won't be possible to have the index.html at the root i.e. `/index.html` and `/api` without manually prefixing your services, because of the way the AppHost listener works. But as I said `/api/index.html` should work given that `index.html` is in your executing directory.

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff You can configure the root directory programatically in the `EndPointHostConfig` using `WebHostPhysicalPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)` You could set it to any path the application can access.

Comment: I'm not sure, it wasn't/isn't working for me. I just did a find and replace to change all my `Routes` to `api/<route>` is how I got around it..

Answer (score 4):

According To [this ServiceStack article](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Run-servicestack-side-by-side-with-another-web-framework) you just need to set it through the config, like this:

```cs
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    SetConfig(new HostConfig { HandlerFactoryPath = "api" });
}
```

Combine that with this [answer from Mythz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12590647/1795053) and you got yourself a self-hosted app at `/api/`:

```cs
_apphost.Start("http://localhost:1337/api/");
```

Note: this seems to have worked for the self-hosted API, but then it fails to serve up its razor pages.  So this isn't quite right.  Still, leaving the answer for now until a full solution is found.